# Suggestions for calculating peak times using entrance and exit times

Tags: distributions, mode

I have a set of data containing the entrance and exit times/dates of visitors to a building and I need to calculate the peak time(s) of said building. With just this information is there a way to calculate the absolute busiest hour? Not on a specific day but generally (i.e. 4pm is, historically, the busiest hour).

I have calculated the frequency of arrivals and exits during each hour but I'm concerned this approach neglects all the time in which a person is inside the building, for example they arrive at 4pm and leave at 7pm but they're not represented on my charts for 5pm or 6pm despite still being present.

Any ideas or suggestions are welcome, needless to say I'm not very experienced/advanced when it comes to statistics.

P.S. I was unsure of which category to tag this question under, sorry if I got it wrong!

Comment: Why not begin by visualizing your data?  The entrance and exit times are readily processed to tell you how many people are inside the building at *any* time: consider plotting this occupancy over time.  The rest might then be obvious. (As a practical matter, you might want to zero out the occupancy at times you know the building must be empty, otherwise data errors and omissions will propagate through the dataset and perhaps introduce a systematic trend or fluctuation.)

Comment: This sounds like the wrong format to work with the data. You could pretty easily convert entrances and exits into the number of people in the building at a given time. After that, just bin and find the fullest, or fit a curve.

Comment: In case it's not clear, the format @Arya and I are both discussing can be computed easily by representing every entrance with the value of $+1,$ every exit with the value of $-1,$ sorting them by time, and computing their cumulative sum.

Comment: Are the intyerest in numer of enrance/exits, or in total number of people in the building?